# Supply maximum string length to a function

Tags: c++, string

When defining a function which has a char array as one of its arguments, is it recommended to always pass the maximum array length as well as an extra argument? For example:

```
int somefunction(char* inputarray, int maxsizeofarray)
```

Comment: It's recommend to not touch raw arrays with a barge pole if at all possible, use a `std::string` / `std::vector<char>` instead.

Comment: I don't think so. Only if the char* argument is a buffer to be written to and the callee needs to know the max memory available (as in strncpy as opposed to strcpy). If access to the char array is read-only it's not necessary. This assumes that the char array is a 0 terminated string. If it contains raw data of unknow length then yes, like with all arrays a length argument is categorically necessary. But that would not be max length but *actual* length -- the array size may well be larger but not all of it may be used.

Comment: @PeterSchneider thats exactly what my function is doing. But let's assume I am sure that whatever is written to it, will not exceed its length. Should I still pass the maxsize anyway?

Comment: It's wise to provide the max memory available at the target location. The function may be used later elsewhere. Things like strcpy or sprintf have been responsible for the worst bugs and safety issues. You can always provide a default value of -1 indicating that memory can be considered "infinite". Btw -- the others urging you to use containers from the standard library are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C-style strings are usually terminated by the `\0` character. Most, if not all, of the functions from the standard library, such as `strcpy` or `strcmp` expect (and honor!) this convention. I'd suggest that any new function you write adhere to the same convention.

Having said that, in C++ (as opposed to C), I wouldn't use `char*` at all. Instead, I'd use the standard [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) class.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on the function.Example, when you are traversing `char array`  from last element to first element, in that case,it is wise to pass the size. But in C only.In C++, you have `std::string`  .

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to pass the array size when the function is writing to the array, or when it's problematic for the function to determine the size thereof (because it's not necessarily following a convention such as having a NUL terminator).  For example:

```
int read(char* buffer, size_t n);
char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);

struct BinaryBlob
{
    BinaryBlob(const char* buffer, size_t n);
    ...
};
```